# Minimum required apps for Android AOSP?

Tags: applications, apk, kiosk-mode, aosp

I am building AOSP Android 5.1 to run on custom hardware that should run a single APK application (as a launcher). The hardware has a camera, speakers, microphone, wifi and LCD screen. There is no cellular or phone functionality. The device is similar to a tablet.

My goal is to create the minimum viable build of Android with no extra apps, (such as Browser, Google Apps etc.) except the bare essentials. This build of Android will launch a single Launcher application. This can be thought of as a kiosk type device.

Note: I would like to keep a few apps for debugging purposes such as Settings, Camera and Sound Recorder, but these will be removed eventually also.

Here are the list of installed packages installed.

`$ adb shell
shell@tulip-p1:/ $ pm list packages -f`

Which can be removed?

`package:/system/priv-app/TelephonyProvider/TelephonyProvider.apk=com.android.providers.telephony
package:/system/priv-app/MediaProvider/MediaProvider.apk=com.android.providers.media
package:/system/app/DocumentsUI/DocumentsUI.apk=com.android.documentsui
package:/system/priv-app/ExternalStorageProvider/ExternalStorageProvider.apk=com.android.externalstorage
package:/system/app/HTMLViewer/HTMLViewer.apk=com.android.htmlviewer
package:/system/priv-app/MmsService/MmsService.apk=com.android.mms.service
package:/system/app/SoundRecorder/SoundRecorder.apk=com.android.soundrecorder
package:/system/priv-app/DefaultContainerService/DefaultContainerService.apk=com.android.defcontainer
package:/system/app/PacProcessor/PacProcessor.apk=com.android.pacprocessor
package:/system/app/CertInstaller/CertInstaller.apk=com.android.certinstaller
package:/system/framework/framework-res.apk=android
package:/system/app/Camera2/Camera2.apk=com.android.camera2
package:/system/priv-app/BackupRestoreConfirmation/BackupRestoreConfirmation.apk=com.android.backupconfirm
package:/system/app/Provision/Provision.apk=com.android.provision
package:/system/priv-app/SettingsProvider/SettingsProvider.apk=com.android.providers.settings
package:/system/priv-app/SharedStorageBackup/SharedStorageBackup.apk=com.android.sharedstoragebackup
package:/system/app/webview/webview.apk=com.android.webview
package:/system/priv-app/InputDevices/InputDevices.apk=com.android.inputdevices
package:/system/priv-app/OneTimeInitializer/OneTimeInitializer.apk=com.android.onetimeinitializer
package:/system/priv-app/Telecom/Telecom.apk=com.android.server.telecom
package:/system/app/KeyChain/KeyChain.apk=com.android.keychain
package:/system/app/PackageInstaller/PackageInstaller.apk=com.android.packageinstaller
package:/system/app/PicoTts/PicoTts.apk=com.svox.pico
package:/system/priv-app/ProxyHandler/ProxyHandler.apk=com.android.proxyhandler
package:/system/app/LatinIME/LatinIME.apk=com.android.inputmethod.latin
package:/system/priv-app/ManagedProvisioning/ManagedProvisioning.apk=com.android.managedprovisioning
package:/system/app/WAPPushManager/WAPPushManager.apk=com.android.smspush
package:/system/app/OpenWnn/OpenWnn.apk=jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
package:/system/priv-app/Settings/Settings.apk=com.android.settings
package:/system/priv-app/VpnDialogs/VpnDialogs.apk=com.android.vpndialogs
package:/system/priv-app/TeleService/TeleService.apk=com.android.phone
package:/system/priv-app/Shell/Shell.apk=com.android.shell
package:/system/app/UserDictionaryProvider/UserDictionaryProvider.apk=com.android.providers.userdictionary
package:/system/priv-app/FusedLocation/FusedLocation.apk=com.android.location.fused
package:/system/priv-app/SystemUI/SystemUI.apk=com.android.systemui
package:/system/app/Bluetooth/Bluetooth.apk=com.android.bluetooth
package:/system/priv-app/ContactsProvider/ContactsProvider.apk=com.android.providers.contacts
package:/system/app/CaptivePortalLogin/CaptivePortalLogin.apk=com.android.captiveportallogin`

Comment: Note: this question is only asking which app are required by Android. Not how to create kiosk-mode or writing a custom ROM.